# When I upload files on Firefox, does it reveal the file location?

Tags: upload

If I upload a file to a website, can they see the folder name it was located in, and the path?

Comment: This question is offtopic, as it does not relate to ubuntu in paticular, but is a question related to webdevlopment. The correct place to ask this kind of question would be stackoverflow.com. But to answer your question: No.

Answer (score 2):

No, the path to the file (including the directory it is in) is hidden, or truncated. All they will see is the name of the file after /fakepath/filename.

Answer (score 2):

[Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#File_inputs) and other major browsers implement [a fakepath mechanism](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#common-input-element-apis):

> **filename**
>   On getting, return the string "C:\fakepath\" followed by the name of
>   the first file in the list of selected files, if any, or the empty
>   string if the list is empty.

So the site will see something like `C:\fakepath\filename`.

Comment: Good asnwer, sorry I already marked the other one.